# Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Гражданин ростом в сажень, но в плечах узок, худ неимоверно, и физиономия, прошу заметить, глумливая.
Почему после слова "неимоверно" ставится запятая? Как я понимаю, это перечисление, значит перед "и" не должно быть запятой.

Пример: петрушка, укроп и салат.
Перед И не ставится запятая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Гражданин ростом в сажень, но в плечах узок, худ неимоверно], и [физиономия, прошу заметить, глумливая]. Запятая разделяет простые предложения в сложном, это не простое предложение с однородными членами.